# TypeError: option values must be strings when setting database url (Alembic)

Tags: python, fastapi, alembic

In this FastAPI projet I'm trying to load an environment variable called **DATABASE_URL** inside Alembic **env.py** file and use it as follows:

**env.py**

```py
from alembic import context
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

config = context.config
load_dotenv('./../.env')
DATABASE_URL = os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")
config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', DATABASE_URL)
```

**.env**

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql+mysqldb://root:123321@localhost/MyDatabase
```

My **.env** file location relative to env.py:

```
alembic/
    env.py
app/
.env

...
```

I tried using the python shell to check whether **DATABASE_URL** is being loaded and it did. Wrapping the **DATABASE_UR** in str() did not help.

Could you show me a way to resolve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found out after a while that **load_env()** must be supplied with **a full .env path** in order to properly load the environment variables from **.env** file, not just a relative path, or else the environment variables will be **None**, hence the **TypeError**.

Therefore, I changed my **env.py** file as follows:

```py
from alembic import context
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

config = context.config

BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) # get current env.py path
load_dotenv(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../', '.env')) # full path to .env
DATABASE_URL = os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")
config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', DATABASE_URL)
```